# Xamarin.Droid - Could not load assembly System.Web.Mvc

Tags: xamarin

I saw multiples post/question about it on StackOverflow but about ASP.NET

I am getting the following:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
>   File name: 'System.Web.Mvc.dll'
>     at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference reference, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00099] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5749/9cfa7836/source/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:229 
>     at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference reference) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5749/9cfa7836/source/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:179 
>     at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] assemblies, Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly, System.Boolean topLevel) [0x0015c] in <998d78d5ee6d46b491b77aff8eeaf856>:0 
>     at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver) [0x001c7] in <998d78d5ee6d46b491b77aff8eeaf856>:0  (NightLine.Droid)

Now the interesting point is that my project isn't an ASP.NET project att all x) So first, what the hell?

I did this video: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Snack-Pack-15-Upgrading-to-XamarinForms-to-NET-Standard

I upgrated the .NET Standard project to 2.0. My Android target is 8.0 and the compiler as well. I tried to upgrade all of my Xamarin.Android.* packages but no success...

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Please list out your dependency list as well.

Comment: I just understood why, I'll explain as soon as I can, it's just an error about Cloudinary NuGet